# Record synchronized video and audio into container file with gstreamer

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer

I am using a TI DM365 EVM to record video and audio.  I need to encode these two streams and save them in a container file like .avi or .mp4.  I am using the following gstreamer pipeline:

> gst-launch v4l2src always-copy=FALSE num-buffers=-1 do-timestamp=TRUE ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)NV12,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1' ! queue ! TIVidenc1 codecName=h264enc engineName=codecServer byteStream=false genTimeStamps=true ! queue ! mux. alsasrc num-buffers=-1 typefind=TRUE do-timestamp=TRUE ! audio/x-raw-int,width=16 ! queue ! TIAudenc1 codecName=aaclcenc engineName=codecServer genTimeStamps=true name=aenc ! queue ! mux. avimux name=mux ! filesink location=vidaudtest.avi sync=true

The result is that I get an .avi file, but when I play the file back on a PC using Totem Movie Player, the video plays too quickly while the audio plays at regular speed.  For example, in a 5 minute file, the video finishes playing in 40 seconds.

Also, while recording, I get several of these messages:

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: Can't record audio fast enough
Additional debug info:
gstbaseaudiosrc.c(822): gst_base_audio_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
Dropped 33516 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
```

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  Any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is that your device cannot deliver frames at the rate you requested.
a possible solution is to "re-sample" your video-stream, by running it through a `videorate` element:

```
v4l2src ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)NV12,width=1280,height=720' ! videorate force-fps=30  ! ...
```

**UPDATE**: alternatively something like this could work as well:

```
... ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)NV12,width=1280,height=720' ! videorate ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! ...
```

Comment: I did a gst-inspect of videorate and it doesn't have the force-fps parameter.  I tried using just videorate without the parameter, but it didn't help.  I am able to record the video stream with no audio into an avi container, however.  Are there any other parameters I could tweak?

Comment: hmm, my `videorate` (gst-plugins-base-0.10.36) does have the firce-fps field.